# Set Start and End Time according to time zone for .Ical files?

Tags: c#, icalendar

I am using C# code to generate .ics files to add my events to outlook calander.

.ics  file is generating fine with the following code.
But i hav eone issue here that is to set start/end time according to time zones. For exampel I have Singapore Standard Time start/End Time for .ics file. I want that if someone opens file in Singapore then it should show Singapore time and if some one opens it in india then it should show Indian Time. Like 2012-04-20 13:00 this time in india will be 10:30Am So .ics file show show 10:30 as start time if .ics file opned in india.

I want that start and end time should be according to the Time Zone of the system . so what is wrong with the following code that its not working.

Please Help.

Code:

```
DateTime StartTime = DateTime.Parse("2012-04-20 13:00:00.000Z");//Singapore Standard Time
DateTime EndTime = DateTime.Parse("2012-04-20 14:00:00.000Z");//Singapore Standard Time
bool UseAlarm = true;
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(450);
                    sb.Append("BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n");
                    sb.Append("BEGIN:VEVENT\n\n");
                    sb.Append("DTSTART:");
                    sb.Append(StartTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd\\THHmmss\\Z"));
                    sb.Append("\nDTEND:");
                    sb.Append(EndTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd\\THHmmss\\Z"));
                    sb.Append("\nLOCATION:");
                    sb.Append("Location"); 
                    sb.Append("\nCATEGORIES:");
                    sb.Append(string.Empty);
                    sb.Append("\nTRANSP:OPAQUE\n");
                    sb.Append("SEQUENCE:0\n");
                    sb.AppendFormat("UID:RFCALITEM{0}\n", DateTime.Now.Ticks); 
                    sb.Append("DTSTAMP:");
                    sb.Append(StartTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd\\THHmmss\\Z"));
                    sb.Append("\nX-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:");//
                    sb.Append("This is just for testing."); 
                    sb.Append("\nSUMMARY:");
                    sb.Append("Title:Test ICS File"); 
                    sb.Append("\n\nPRIORITY:");
                    sb.Append(5);
                    sb.Append("\nCLASS:PUBLIC\n");
                    if (UseAlarm)
                    {
                        sb.Append("BEGIN:VALARM\n");
                        sb.Append("TRIGGER:PT15M\n");
                        sb.Append("ACTION:DISPLAY\n");
                        sb.Append("DESCRIPTION:Reminder\n");
                        sb.Append("PRIORITY:5\n");
                        sb.Append("END:VALARM\n");
                    }
                    sb.Append("END:VEVENT\n"); 
                    sb.Append("END:VCALENDAR");
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't like to stake my life on how Outlook will handle iCal data, so none of this is guaranteed... However, there are a few misconceptions in your code:

```
//Singapore Standard Time
DateTime StartTime = DateTime.Parse("2012-04-20 13:00:00.000Z");
```

The "Z" here means "Zulu time" - so `DateTime.Parse` interprets this as a UTC value, and then converts it to the local time on the system running the code. So on my machine, for example (in UK time, which is UTC+1 on April 20th 2012) this creates a `DateTime` value which has a time of 14:00.

If you want the value to be parsed as a *local* date/time, you shouldn't have the "Z" there.

When you *write* the value, you can (IIRC - it's a while since I've done any iCal work) express the date/time one of three ways:

- As a UTC value by including the "Z" (as you currently do *incorrectly* - you're including Z at the end of a *local* value), thereby confusing things
- As a general "local" date/time with no specified time zone, e.g. "wake me up to 8am wherever I am"
- As a date/time in a *specific* time zone

(Consult [RFC 2445](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt) for details of the format of each type.)

It's not clear which of these you want - the first is probably the simplest, but you'll need to use the *UTC* date/time, not the local one.

One point: .NET isn't really helping you here, by confusing things with `DateTime`. You may wish to consider using my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) project which keeps "local date/time" and "date/time in a particular zone" separate.